# superfish menu bug in IE compatibility view mode

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I've implemented a drop down menu with super-fish plugin. It's OK in **IE(version 8,9, 10)** but when i change browser mode(F12) into compatibility view, right side of the menu shrinks. When i mouse over,it becomes correct. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please could you provide the html and css and if possible, try to produce a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the error so that we are able to help you out.

Comment: so the solution is simple: Don't use compatibility mode.

Comment: By the way, your last paragraph really doesn't make any sense. You probably need to rewrite that bit of the question completely.

Comment: Thank you Pete. I really appreciate you in advance.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/YauzE/

Comment: I cannot view your menu properly, it has application code in it. But try applying the CSS style `zoom:1;` on the elements of your menu, it might snap your elements back into shape.

Comment: sorry,I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/YauzE/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer...For fixing this problem, i changed this " .sf-menu{ width:100%;}" to .sf-menu{width:500px;} in superfish-rtl.css.now the menu is ok and works correctly even when i move mouse over it in compatibility view mode.anyway thank you everybody.